# unable to read json

Tags: python, json, nan, unexpected-token

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-7c5fcf8552e0> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df2 = pd.read_json('/content/drive/MyDrive/Hackathon project/PS 1,2/no_pii_action_history.json')

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1319         if orient == "columns":
   1320             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1321                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1322             )
   1323         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding 'NaN'
```

we tried 2 methods

1)

```
df2 = pd.read_json('/content/drive/MyDrive/Hackathon project/PS 1,2/no_pii_action_history.json')
```

2. 

```
import json

def handle_nan(value):
    if value == "nan":  # replace "nan" with the appropriate representation of NaN in your data
        return float('nan')
    return value

# Specify the file path
file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Hackathon project/PS 1,2/no_pii_action_history.json'

# Open the file and load JSON data with custom handling
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file, object_hook=handle_nan)
```

both methods are not working

Comment: `"NaN"` is a parse error; `object_hook` gets called *after* parsing, to tell `json.load` what to do with the key/value pairs read from a valid JSON object. (For example, it can be used to build something other than a Python `dict` if the object has duplicate keys.)

Comment: ```ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding 'NaN'. ```
The error you're encountering suggests that there is an issue with the way ```'NaN'``` values are represented in your JSON file. JSON standard only supports numeric values and does not have a representation for ```'NaN'``` which is specific to Python. Hence, when pandas tries to read a JSON with ```'NaN'``` as a value, it throws an error because it's not a valid JSON token.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to parse something that is not valid JSON. An `object_hook` isn't going to help with that.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to replace NaN with null in Json file.
It's hard to respond without seeing the json file